# PHP não acha Sessão

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Olá! Estou fazendo um login com Jquery e PHP, a conexão está certa. Mas quando eu logo ao invés de me manter em uma página ele não acha minha sessão e me envia de volta pro login.

Meu HTML:

```html
<h2 id="errolog">Usuário ou senha errados!</h2>
    
<form id="formlogin">
 <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" required="" />
 <input type="password" id="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="" />
 <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#errolog').hide(); //Esconde o elemento com id errolog
$('#formlogin').submit(function(){  //Ao submeter formulário
var login=$('#email').val(); //Pega valor do campo email
var senha=$('#senha').val(); //Pega valor do campo senha
$.ajax({   //Função AJAX
  url:"manifesta_login22.php",   //Arquivo php
  type:"post",    //Método de envio
  data: "login="+login+"&senha="+senha, //Dados
    success: function (result){   //Sucesso no AJAX
                if(result==1){
                  location.href='restrito.php' //Redireciona
                }else{
                  $('#errolog').show();  //Informa o erro
                }
            }
})
return false; //Evita que a página seja atualizada
})
})
</script>
```

Conexão com PHP:

```html
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","login2");

  $login=$_POST['login']; //Pegando dados passados por AJAX
  $senha=$_POST['senha'];

  //Consulta no banco de dados
  $sql="select * from usuarios where email='".$login."' and senha='".md5($senha)."'";
  $resultados = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());
  $res=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados); //
 if (@mysqli_num_rows($resultados) == 0) {
  echo 0; //Se a consulta não retornar nada é porque as credenciais estão erradas
 }

 else {
  echo 1; //Responde sucesso
  if(!isset($_SESSION)) { //verifica se há sessão aberta
  session_start();  //Inicia seção
  //Abrindo seções
  $_SESSION['usuarioID']=$res['id'];
  $_SESSION['nomeUsuario']=$res['nome'];
  $_SESSION['email']=$res['email'];
  exit;
 }
  }
?>
```

Página logada:

```html
<?php
session_start();  //A seção deve ser iniciada em todas as páginas
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuarioID'])) {  //Verifica se há seções
          header("Location: login.html"); //Redireciona o visitante para login
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não usou o session_start() no topo do seu código de conexão, então ele não identifica nada. O session_start() precisa estar no topo do código php, é padrão da documentação e regra.

Comment: Olá! Coloquei no topo da Conexão com PHP e continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: Tente colocar o seu data do ajax assim -  data: login:login, senha:senha. A forma que está usando é para o método GET, neste seu caso é POST. Se não funcionar, talvez seja a conexão do mysqli na forma de entrega dos dados e possivelmente a biblioteca que não está instalada do mysqli.